# Serilog, Loggly-csharp, FullNetFx

Tags: .net, serilog, loggly

I've got a .net 4.5.2 application where I'm trying to integrate with Serilog and Loggly.

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. Creating the
>   instance for type IApplicationLog failed. Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Serilog.FullNetFx, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I've tried with the latest version of Loggly-csharp (4.6.0.2) and 4.5.1.11 but still get the same error. The Serilog version is 2.2.0.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I'm setting up serilog and loggly through appsettings.

- Serilog 2.2.0
- Serilog.Settings.AppSettings 2.0.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Loggly 2.0.11
- Loggly-csharp 4.5.1.11
- Loggly-csharp-config 4.5.1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serilog.Sinks.Loggly hasn't yet been updated to Serilog 2.0.

There's an active pull request adding this support at: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-loggly/pull/5